# How can I install sp72886.exe silently/unattended

Tags: windows, installshield, silent-installer

Product Name: HP ProBook 6470b
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit)

I would like to install sp72886.exe silently in my Laptop.

I tried the below commands

```
sp72886.exe -s -a -silent

sp72886.exe /S /v/qn
```

but always InstallShield wizard pops up.

I even tried sp72886.cva file with below configurations

```
1

[Install Execution]
Install="setup.exe"
SilentInstall="setup.exe" /S "/v /qn"



2

[Install Execution]
Install="setup.exe"
SilentInstall="setup.exe" -s -r
```

but no hopes.

Thanks in advance

- Alen

Answer (score 0):

First extract the sp72886.exe file with 7-Zip. Inside the sp72886.exe is the real install file.

This you should install with

```
setup.exe /S /v/qn
```

Thats the hint the installer gives you when opening via `setup.exe /?`.